# How to undo git config --system core.askpass git-gui--askpass

Tags: git, github

Ran that command when trying to fix a problem I was having with git push. It prompts me every time I git push and I have no idea how to disable it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try running:

```
git config --system --unset-all core.askpass
```

to remove that configuration.  You can then run `git config --system --list` to view the full list of system configurations to ensure it's gone.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you can edit your git config file:

https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

> First, a quick review: Git uses a series of configuration files to determine non-default behavior that you may want. The first place Git
>   looks for these values is in an /etc/gitconfig file, which contains
>   values for every user on the system and all of their repositories. If
>   you pass the option --system to git config, it reads and writes from
>   this file specifically.
>
> The next place Git looks is the ~/.gitconfig (or ~/.config/git/config)
>   file, which is specific to each user. You can make Git read and write
>   to this file by passing the --global option.
>
> Finally, Git looks for configuration values in the configuration file
>   in the Git directory (.git/config) of whatever repository you’re
>   currently using. These values are specific to that single repository.
>
> Each of these “levels” (system, global, local) overwrites values in
>   the previous level, so values in .git/config trump those in
>   /etc/gitconfig, for instance.
>
> **Git’s configuration files are plain-text, so you can also set these
>   values by manually editing the file and inserting the correct syntax.
>   It’s generally easier to run the git config command, though.**