# How to remove github login popup asking for credentials?

Tags: git, github

I changed my Github account recently. I have my new username and email stored in global .gitconfig:

```
[filter "lfs"]
    process = git-lfs filter-process
    required = true
    clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
    smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
[user]
    name = myusername
    email = myemail@gmail.com
[credential]
    helper = store
    username = myusername
```

and my password for github in .git-credentials.

Every time I push to my remote repository Github login pops up asking me for my credentials.

[image: Github login popup]

And when I cancel it everything works fine. I don't need to enter username or password. Remote is updated.
How to get rid of that popup? I didn't have that behaviour before changing account credentials.

Comment: As of 2022, `guiPrompt = false` property worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73137673/7505906

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Git has the concept of multiple credential managers.  When you installed Git for Windows, it came with the Git Credential Manager for Windows (either the old one or Core), and you probably answered a question about whether you wanted to use it or not.

Somewhere in an earlier config file, such as the system one, there's a setting that looks like `credential.helper = manager`.  Because Git invokes the credential managers in order and uses the first one that provides it credentials, it first asks the `manager` one specified at the system level, causing the pop-up, and then invokes the `store` one in your local config file.

What likely happened is that your old account was using the `manager` helper but the new one is using the `store` helper for saving your password, so the prompt didn't show up for `manager` because it had your credentials saved.

If you don't find the `manager` helper, run `git config -l --show-origin` to find the file which has the other `credential.helper` setting and then edit it to remove that option.

Do note that the `manager` helper is going to be more secure than storing your credentials in a file on disk (since it will be encrypted), and it will use a personal access token, which GitHub will require in the future, so you may want to use the popup prompt to get credentials and remove the `store` helper instead.

Comment: I have removed `manager` setting as you proposed and it worked.

Comment: But if I remove `store` option, as you recommended, I stil get popup every time I try to `git push` and it doesn't connect now, but asks me in command line for password, and then connects.

Comment: I have updated Git for Windows and it created a new entry in Credential Manager in Windows (which I must have deleted when changing credentials) and now everything works perfectly. And in the way you recommended for security reasons. Thank you very much.

Comment: I tried this a while ago because I kept getting a pop up, but now I want to revert it, which file should I mess with? (and what do I add?)

Comment: If you want to re-add a credential helper, you can add one in `~/.gitconfig`.  That would be the `.gitconfig` file in your home directory.

Answer (score 4):

I got this same problem today, got an email from Github that the way I accessed the git has been deprecated, so solved it as below:

1. uninstall the git software ( Or, using `Run > appwiz.cpl` )
2. install new git from here - https://git-scm.com/downloads
3. for one time save password - run the below command for this project:

   `git config --global credential.helper store`
4. now run below:

   `git pull`

Note:

1. To run the 3rd & 4th command, you should already be in a git folder (where you ran the `git clone https://github.com/../...git` command)
2. This issue occurred because now the GitHub changed it's authentication:
   from `git credential manager`
   to `git credential manager core`
   See below for more information

> Basic authentication using a password to Git is deprecated and will soon no longer work. Visit https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/

Comment: step 2 solve my problem by its own (installing new git also remove old one on windows)

Answer (score 0):

This issue mainly occur when you try to push from  VScode integrated terminal

Try pushing the commits directly from git bash
or
run these command  just after you open VScode

```html
git remote set-url origin  <repo-link>



git remote set-url origin https://<your github username>:<your password>@github.com/<your github username>/<your github repository name>.git
```

the last command saves your credentials for that particular session   and wont ask again until you close and reopen VScode

Comment: for me <host in ssh config>:<username>/<repo name> worked